# Google search console Live Indexing failed with Server error (5xx)

Tags: robots.txt, google-search-console, google-index

My website was crawling by google perfectly until this last February, 2023. The website didn't have any robots.txt until now. Suddenly Page Indexing live test is failing due to this error

```
Failed: Robots.txt unreachable.
```

I added robots.txt in my react website with the following robots.txt content.

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
```

I also able to see this robots.txt through my browser after deployment. I am using AWS for the deployment.

```
myexample.com/robots.txt
```

But when I try to test the Live Index test, It throws

```
Failed: Server error (5xx)
```

Why is it throwing server error after I update robots.txt?

Note: It was working perfectly until this last February without robots.txt. I didn't do any development changes from last December? Why suddenly its showing these error while Google indexing?

Comment: I voted to close this question because a 500 error is a very generic "something went wrong" error. It could be a misconfiguration, a permissions problem, or a coding error. More information about the specific cause of your error is available in your server's error log. There is no way to accurately answer this question without seeing the logs. Any answers here will be guesses and there are hundreds if not thousands of possible answers.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller : There has been no change done on the code and more over the site is still up and running without any errors until now. We started to notice this issue only for the last two month on google search console which means without robots.txt file the crawler was working fine.

Comment: There's no way to help you without the information from your server logs. That is the only place that you can figure out the cause of a 500 error

Comment: I have the same issue. this never happened for any of my sites before. i think this is some update that google made on their side. unfortunately i dont have a suggested fix yet, so ill stay tuned.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue with my Next.js 13-based website. I kept receiving a Failed: Server error (5xx) message despite my website functioning properly.

After an extensive search for a solution, I discovered that the problem was caused by my approach to handling internationalization (i18n) on my website.

Specifically, the issue was related to how I was retrieving the locale from the "accept-language" header. To resolve this, I followed Next.js guidelines on handling i18n and implemented their recommended method. This resolved my problem and restored the proper functioning of my website.[NextJS internationalization](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/internationalization#routing-overview)

Although we don't know your exact setup, I hope I have given you some useful guidance or idea where the issue would be.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using next.js, modify middleware.js to

```js
export const config = {
    matcher: ['/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|assets|favicon.ico|sw.js|sitemap.xml|robots.txt).*)']
}
```